# my if statement does not pick up

Tags: netbeans, boolean

This is my problem: when I run my code, it's supposed to check if two boo-leans condition. One is supposed to be false and the other true. I also put in a else code in it, and coded System-out-print ERROR and whatever the boo-leans values were. When I run it, it printed out that one WAS false and one WAS true but it didn't get caught by the if statement. This is my code:

```
    ' if((falseOnce = false)&(tAndCSelected = true)){//these are my two booleans
         String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Register";//place where database Register is
     try{
                         String sql = "INSERT INTO Register(Username, Password, Email,Title,Prediction,Date_Joined) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                       String usernme = "nbuser";
                       String passed ="nbuser";
                       Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usernme,passed);//makes a connector to the database
                         java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();//gets date
                        java.util.Date date = cal.getTime();
                        java.sql.Date sqldate = new Date(date.getTime());
                         PreparedStatement action = connection.prepareStatement(sql);                            
                         action.setString(1, uname);//in first position, username goes in
                         action.setString(2,password);
                         action.setString(3,email.getText());
                         action.setString(4,null);
                         action.setString(5,null);
                         action.setDate(6,sqldate);
                         action.executeUpdate();//executes the instructions
                         redirect.setText("Your account has been created. You may now log in");
                         new Timer(3000,null);//3 seconds before going back to logIn page.
                         new LogIn().setVisible(true);
                         setVisible(false);
       }catch(SQLException e){
     System.out.println("unsuccessful"+e);
       }
 }
 else{
     System.out.println("ERROR" + "falseOnce is " + falseOnce + "and tAndCSelected is"       + tAndCSelected );
 }
    '
```

The rest of the code is just inputting data into a database IF the two booleans condition is as I say they are. What is the problem?

Comment: You need to use ==, not =.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if((falseOnce = false)&(tAndCSelected = true))
```

You have too little of each operator... in Java, equality comparison is `==`, not `=`, and logical and is `&&`, not `&`. That should be

```
if((falseOnce == false)&&(tAndCSelected == true))
```

or more concisely just

```
if(!falseOnce && tAndCSelected)
```

(`=` alone is the assignment operator, `&` alone is the binary AND)